# Alternative for deprecated finalize method in java for JNI

Tags: java, c++, performance, memory-management, java-native-interface

I have a requirement to implement a bidirectional communication between C++ and Java where i use JNI. Most of the issues are solved by using JNI but i am worried more where i pass a pointer reference of a variable in heap memory of C++ to Java. I use the `new` keyword to allocate the reference in the heap memory and pass it to Java for future references to that particular variable. So, I've to use `delete` to deallocate the variable from the heap memory of C++. Usually in Java this is achieved by using overriding `finalize()` method so the garbage collector invokes this method when deleting an object, but i see that `finalize` is deprecated from Java 9. Is there any other way to achieve the required functionality?

C++ Code (Passing C++ Object reference to Java):

```
jobject Helper::toJavaHistory(const History& history) {

    auto* historyPtr = new History(history);
    jobject historyObject = getEnv()->NewObject(getHistoryClass(), getMethodID("History","<init>"),reinterpret_cast<jlong>(historyPtr));
    return historyObject;
}
```

Java Code:

```
public class History {
    
    public long historyPointer;

    public History(long historyPointer){
        this.historyPointer = historyPointer;
    }
    native void deleteHistory(long historyPtr);

}
```

JNI Native Implementation C++:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_core_History_deleteHistory
        (JNIEnv * env, jobject thisHistoryObject, jlong historyPtr) {
    auto* history = reinterpret_cast<History*>(historyPtr);
    delete history;
}
```

Comment: I suggest this is off-topic as C++ - although the OP is working with JNI, the question is about alternatives to a deprecated language/JVM feature in Java, interfacing from C++ will be via JNI (which is also part of the Java universe) so alternatives will ultimately be specified on the "Java side".

Comment: Thank you, i came across using Cleaner and found this video to be helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN18Sy6mMpQ . Together with your comment and the video I'm able to get the whole approach.

Comment: The better alternative is not to use native `new` for such an allocation in the first place. Allocate a direct `ByteBuffer` and place the native object into it (see JNI functions `NewDirectByteBuffer` and `GetDirectBufferAddress`). When you store a reference to the `ByteBuffer` object into the Java `History` object, you get the automatic cleanup for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I voted to reopen this question as the linked duplicate did not show a way to do this for JNI code)

The Cleaner API introduced in Java 9 allows you to register `Runnable` objects when your object becomes unreachable and thus eligible for garbage collection.

I will show two equivalent approaches that involve JNI methods. Both require you to associate a `Cleaner` with your History class:

```
static Cleaner cleaner = cleaner.create();
```

For you, the end goal is to call the `static` (!) `deleteHistory` method on the `long` holding the variable state.

## The long approach

Since `Cleaner`s want a `Runnable`, let us define one:

```
static class HistoryCleaner implements Runnable {
  private long ptr;
  public HistoryCleaner(long ptr) { this.ptr = ptr; }
  public void run() {
    History.deleteHistory(this.ptr);
  }
}
```

Make sure that `HistoryCleaner` does not create any reference to your `Cleaner` object, as that causes a reference cycle and will prevent the object from being garbage-collected.

For more advanced use cases, you can define the `run` method as `native` and implement it in c++ as

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HistoryCleaner_run(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) { ... }
```

Keep in mind that the `thiz` object is your `HistoryCleaner`, not the `History` object.
The constructor can now look like this:

```
public History(long historyPointer){
    this.historyPointer = historyPointer;
    this.cleanable = cleaner.register(this, new HistoryCleaner(historyPointer));
}
```

## Short-hand

You can use lambda syntax to skip creating a `Runnable`, but you must take care *not* to reference anything about the object. Thus, the constructor can become:

```
public History(long historyPtr){
    this.historyPointer = historyPtr;
    this.cleanable = cleaner.register(this, () -> History.deleteHistory(historyPtr));
    // Note: historyPtr is a local variable so this does not keep a reference to the object.
}
```

## A note on (Auto)Closable

As the Cleaner documentation shows, the `cleanable` object returned by `Cleaner#register` is useful to implement the `Closeable#close` method:

```
public void close() {
   cleanable.clean();
}
```

This allows you to use the java try-with-resources form to implicitly call `deleteHistory` for you OR call it automatically for you if you forget.

Comment: I used the short-hand approach which i got to know from the post linked but a dedicated answer would save a lot of time though, thank you for it.